porque no puedo importar a java.sql.connection

estoy creando un sistema de ventas pero al querer importar a java.sql.connection no me aparece y ya agregue la libreria

Una cosa es agregar la librería, otra cosa es importarla.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

@Comunidad ,soy un novato en la programacion disculpa el problema es en que no lo puedo importar  y viendo unos tutoriales me salia que tenia que agregar la libreria pero sigue el problema

Buenas Brandon, Como bien te ha puesto @padaleiana, Una cosa es agregar la librería, otra cosa es importarla. Tu ya la has añadido, pero te falta importarla. Para ello tendrás que poner Import nombre_de_la_clase, que normalmente suele ser import java.sql.Connection;. De todas formas, si haces clic en la bombilla o circulo amarillo que te aparece, te suele poner más información sobre el error, y muchas veces como solucionarlo. (Él mismo te ofrece un botón para hacer el import)

en eso es el problema cuando hago el import no me aparece @Maida

Tienes que poner, justo debajo de la declaración de package, lo siguiente: import java.sql.Connection; Si al poner eso da algún error, entonces es que no has agregado correctamente los archivos de JDBC.

si eso ya lo hice ahora cuando quiero importar el DriverMananger no me sale y cuando lo escribo me sale error @A.Cedano

Para el DriverManager tienes que poner import java.sql.DriverManager;. Y por favor pulsa en [edit] para agregar el código como lo tienes ahora. Indica también el error que marca. Si has agregado correctamente JDBC no debe dar problema ninguno de los import relativos a esa herramienta.

@brandonlopez que error obtienes cuando importas???

@Jorgesys cuando escribo el import a java.sql.Connection; no me sale error pero cuando importe a java.sql.Drivermanger me sale error, se subraya de color rojo

@brandonlopez es que mencionabas en tu pregunta que tratas de  usar la clase Connection y se muestra en rojo, ahora dices que al agregar import java.sql.Connection; no tienes error

¡Si registraste él .jar,

únicamente tienes que agregar el "import"
import java.sql.Connection;

Realiza el siguiente cambio:
package modelo;

import java.sql.Connection;

public class Conexion{

    Connection con;

}


¿cual jar? Es mejor dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta

¿registrarlo de que manera?
